# GraphiQL for Apollo Fine on Desktop, 404 on Laptop?

Tags: meteor, graphql

I've got GraphIQL running fine on my desktop Mac at http://localhost:8080/graphql.

And on my laptop Mac, using the exact same code synced via Github, I show this in the console:

> GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:8080/graphql

...which appears to indicate that graphql is connected. But accessing
http://localhost:8080/graphql brings up a 404 error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /graphql was not found on this server

I even deleted my node_modules folder and reinstalled from scratch via `meteor npm install`.

Does this make sense to anybody?

Here's the code that sets up Apollo and graphiql:

```
//apollo
import express from 'express';
import { apolloServer } from 'apollo-server';
import Schema from '/imports/api/schema';
import Mocks from '/imports/api/mocks';
import Resolvers from '/imports/api/resolvers';
import Connectors from '/imports/api/db-connectors';

const GRAPHQL_PORT = 8080;

const graphQLServer = express();

graphQLServer.use('/graphql', apolloServer({
    graphiql: true,
    schema: Schema,
    resolvers: Resolvers,
    connectors: Connectors,
    mocks: Mocks,
}));

graphQLServer.listen(GRAPHQL_PORT, () => console.log(
    `GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}/graphql`
));
```

Answer (score 1):

So, this could be because you have something else running on 8080 on your laptop. Maybe try logging uncaught express errors to the console?

Another possibility is that you're not trying exactly the same URL on your desktop. Version 0.2 of apolloServer currently allows only POST requests. When you navigate to the address in your browser, it will try to send a GET request, which will result in a 404. Try spinning up graphiql on a separate route and see if you can access that.

PS: If you get a chance, you should make a PR to the repo where you copy-pasted the code snippet from, so other people won't run into the same issue ;-)

Comment: I rebooted the laptop to kill any running processes, but am still getting the 404 error. The server code is from docs at `http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-server/migration.html`. What is the syntax to get the .listen callback? Googling for `graphQLServer.listen` didn't seem to pull up examples with the callback. I'll add it and see what the error says.

Comment: I just used `npm ls` to compare installed node_modules on the two machines, and found differences, even though the laptop uses the package.json file from the desktop. This may account for the error. I have to rebuild my package.json file to match what's in the desktop node_modules folder.

Comment: I just rebuilt my package.json file using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-collect` on my desktop. It built and ran successfully, accessing `http://localhost:8080/graphql` correctly as before. I then brought the new package.json file into the laptop app folder via git and rebuilt. `http://localhost:8080/graphql` still shows a 404 error on my laptop. I have no clue yet how to debug this. :)

Comment: If anyone can post the callback syntax for the graphQLServer.listen call, I can try that to see what the error message says.

Comment: Could also be that you're getting a 404 because apolloServer only allows POST requests. Try following the instructions for setting up graphiql with apolloServer, and see if you can get that to work in your browser.

Comment: I should add to that that if you're not seeing an EADDRINUSE error in your server console, it probably means that the server started successfully.

Comment: I'm currently using the instructions for setting up graphiql with apolloServer found in the docs at `http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-server/migration.html.` Can you please post a link to the instructions you mention?

Answer (score 0):

I used `npm remove apollo-server` and `npm install apollo-server --save` to update the `apollo-server` npm module, and did the same for `apollo-client`. I then updated to the apollo server 0.2.x code found at `http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-server/migration.html`. I also updated to Meteor 1.4.x. Now the 404 error is gone.